# Speeding up MySQL SELECT query with TRIM, a REPLACE, and another REPLACE on both sides of WHERE IN

Tags: mysql

I am running a query on a couple of somewhat large tables (60,000 and 1,200,000 rows each) that is taking forever (has been running 90 minutes as I write this). Essentially, I'm looking to select where names match in the two tables, trimming each and removing all commas and periods as the use of punctuation varies between the two. The ultimate objective is to DELETE from table_a with the same WHERE requirement. For the moment, I'm just trying to get the SELECT to work reasonably quickly.

Here is the query I am using:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM table_a WHERE TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(name_a,'.',''),',','')) IN (SELECT TRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(name_b,'.',''),',','')) from table_b);
```

Any thoughts on how to make this faster?

Comment: will always be slow unless you can remove functions from where statement

Comment: Such queries (with function on column) will never use indexes and so always be slow. The only way is to introduce a new column where you will keep normalized data (without dots and commas) and have index on it. The column can be filled by trigger.

Comment: If you're using MySQL 5.7 or newer, you can use a generated column and add an index to it.

Comment: Good thoughts. I like the trigger option, but can't use it as pre 5.7. Considering this, however, I realized that I can just update the table_b.name_b (not necessary to keep this one as is) to trim and remove unwanted characters. This would at least bring the cumbersome WHERE down to only one side. If that is not sufficient, I could also create a temp table with the table_a id and name_a, then update name_a in that temp table to then use similarly. It might not be the most elegant way, but it would work. Thanks for the input. It led me to a solution.